# boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source opens a file that has CJK filename

Tags: c++, boost, boost-iostreams

Assume we have code like this:

```
boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source dev(paFileName.u8string().c_str());
```

where `paFileName` is a `std::filesystem::path` object.

On Windows, the internal character in `std::filesystem::path` is `wchar_t`, but `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source` seems to only accept variant width character string. Therefore, we convert the fixed width `wchar_t` string to a variant width `char` string with method `u8string`.

The problem is that the conversion apparently causes the ctor of `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source` unable to find the file in the filesystem, and the ctor will throw a `boost::wrapexcept<std::ios_base::failure[abi:cxx11]>` that says "failed opening file: The system cannot find the file specified."

How to fix this problem? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have some information? Like, what is an example filename? How do you get the filename? Is it hardcoded? How?

Comment: @sehe According to my own experience, any filenames that contain CJK character will have this problem, even if `std::filesystem::exists` confirms that the file does exist, given that the `std::filesystem::path` object is the argument instead of a standard string converted from the path object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the message of the compile-time error:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/iostreams/detail/path.hpp:138:5: note: declared private here
  138 |     path(const std::wstring&);
      |     ^~~~
```

Somehow Boost.Iostreams tried to convert the `std::filesystem::path` into a `boost::iostreams::details::path` but failed, because the conversion ctor that accepts the wide character string is not accessible. This problem doesn't happen on Linux, because the filesystem on Linux usually uses UTF-8 `char` strings as filenames. In contrast, on Windows the filenames are usually UTF-16 `wchar_t` strings.

My workaround is to avoid the conversion ctor mentioned above to be called. I gave a `boost::filesystem::wpath` instead of the original `std::filesystem::path` to Boost.Iostreams, hoping that the Boost version `wpath` is more acceptable to Boost.Iostreams.

```
boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source> fin(
    boost::filesystem::wpath(static_cast<std::wstring>(paFileName))
);
```

And it works.